# mysql procedure how to execute a query that retrieves data within a loop then return a custom value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I don't understand how procedures work even though I search for several topic/tutorial but only found pointless examples.

In PHP my code would look like this:

```
function getFullPathFromID($ID)
{
  $path = '';
  while($result = $c->query("SELECT IDParentFolder,path FROM folders WHERE ID=$ID")->fetch())
  {
    $ID = $result->IDParentFolder;
    $path = $result->path.'/'.$path;
  }
  return $path;
}
```

I couldn't get it working with procedures, I can't even make a query to the db:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE getFullPathFromID(ID INT)    
  BEGIN
    SELECT path FROM folders WHERE ID = ID;
  END
#
```

When I execute it with a valid value I still get "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."

So how can I execute a query that retrieves data within a loop and then return a custom value (concatenation of each step's value)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_IDParentFolder INT;
  DECLARE v_Name VARCHAR(255);
  SET path='';
  REPEAT
    SELECT IDParentFolder,Name INTO v_IDParentFolder, v_Name FROM folders WHERE ID = IDFolder;
    SET IDFolder = v_IDParentFolder;
    SET path = CONCAT(v_Name,'/',path);
  UNTIL v_IDParentFolder IS null END REPEAT;
  SET path = CONCAT('/',path);
END
```

For the "SELECT path FROM folders" I mistook 'path' for 'name' so I couldn't get any result indeed...

For the others beginners in SQL and especially procedures, a SELECT query will not save the result but return it, in order to only save the result "INTO" has to be used as in my code and these variables have to be declared at the beginning of the procedure.

Thanks to the guy who downvoted me, he has been really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your stored procedure because the scalar `id` has the same name as a column in the table.  So, the expression:

```
 where id = id
```

does not do what you expect.

You should write this as:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE getFullPathFromID(v_ID INT)    
  BEGIN
    SELECT path FROM folders f WHERE f.ID = v_ID;
  END
#
```

However, I'm not sure this will fix the problem of no rows being selected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that doesn't work either. Actually I forgot to mention I also tried "SELECT path FROM folders" which doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, using mysqli extension you should prepare to avoid sql injection.

You should not put the query into a loop, you would loop through a recordset, but in your case you are getting a single row so it makes no sense. here 's what you should really do:

```
$query = 'SELECT path FROM folders WHERE ID = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
if ($stmt->execute()){
    $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
    $path = $row['path'];
}
return $path;
```

Comment: I made the PHP code to explain what I want, I don't plan to use it and I kept it simple (that's why it's not prepared). I think you misunderstood my problem, let me rephrase: I only get one result by query and for each step the query is not the same since the IDFolder variable is changed.
The data in the table represent a tree of directories, at each step it gets to the lower level until it reaches the root.
By the way, is there a need of some kind of prepare to the variables sent to a stored procedure?